# How to get static function fields in Python class

Tags: python, class, static

I have a static class with a list of "colors" defined as fields. But each color is actually a time dependent function:

```
class Colors(object):
    @staticmethod
    def RED(t):
        return [255 * t, 0, 0]
```

Then, I have another class that will have these functions as fields:

```
class PathMaker(object):
    SUCCESS_COLOR = Colors.BLUE
    FAIL_COLOR = Colors.RED
```

But now, `PathMaker.FAIL_COLOR` is an unbound method, instead of a reference to `Colors.RED`.

Is there a better way of doing this? I could probably make SUCCESS_COLOR and FAIL_COLOR static methods, but that seems like a bad way of doing it.

Comment: you could switch to Python 3, which doesn't have the same method wrapping weirdness of 2.7.

Comment: Why do you think making FAIL_COLOR a staticmethod is a bad way?

Comment: General design advice: When something looks like a constant, it should be a constant. If it's not, don't make it look like one.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not sure that will actually change anything here.

Comment: @BrenBarn, from my experiments, it seemed to make a difference: [this](http://ideone.com/9duVeZ) Python 2 code gives a TypeError, but the [same code](http://ideone.com/hkpWFF) in Python 3 produces the desired output.

Comment: @Kevin: Interesting!  I didn't realize that Python 3 method binding worked that way.  In Python 3, you don't even need to make RED a staticmethod at all, because Python 3 doesn't pass anything if you call the method on the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the reference with staticmethod works:

```
class Colors(object):
    @staticmethod
    def RED(t):
        return [255 * t, 0, 0]

class PathMaker(object):
    FAIL_COLOR = staticmethod(Colors.RED)

>>> PathMaker.FAIL_COLOR(1)
[255, 0, 0]
>>> PathMaker.FAIL_COLOR(2)
[510, 0, 0]
```

The reason is that the staticmethod descriptor causes accessing `Colors.RED` to "unwrap" the staticmethod and return the underlying "raw" function (not a method).  Without using staticmethod in PathMaker, PathMaker rewraps this function into its own method, just as it would if you defined a function directly in the class body.  By using `staticmethod(Colors.RED)`, you can rewrap the unwrapped function into a staticmethod.